# How to solve a differential equation problem that contains an integral term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ y(x) = \int_{0}^{x} (y(t))^{\frac{1}{2}} dt + 1 $$

What will be a general solution? I couldn't find any related problems in stackexchange. I tried

$$u'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}  (y(t))^{\frac{1}{2}} (y ′ (t))dt $$

and

$$u''(x)  = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{x} y(t)^(1/2) (y ′(t))^2dt$$

But, I couldn't go further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have written is nearly illegible, which is amazing because it is typed.

Answer (score 2):

From $y(x) = \int_{0}^{x} (y(t))^{\frac{1}{2}} dt + 1$ you get, by the FTC, the initial value problem

$y'(x)=(y(x))^{\frac{1}{2}}, $

$y(0)=1$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: sadly...nope...I've met the problems that already given second order equation and y(0), y'(0) given values... as a result, this is quite frustrated problem for me. I get the point now I have to form a initial value problem..and I read the pdf from bard faculty and Pauls about IVP...and...still don't get it! Can you help me, more?

Comment: Yes. A Typo  I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake when you took the derivative $$y(x) = \int_{0}^{x} (y(t))^{\frac{1}{2}} dt + 1$$
$$y'(x) =\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {d}{dx} (\int_{0}^{x} (y(t))^{\frac{1}{2}} dt + 1)$$
And not ( which is what you did) :
$$y'(x) = \frac {d}{dt}(\int_{0}^{x} (y(t))^{\frac{1}{2}} dt + 1)$$
Use the Fondamental Theorem of Calculus 
$$y'=(y(x))^{\frac{1}{2}}.1$$
It's an easy ode to solve...since it's separable

You will have a constant C  to evaluate it use the fact that

$$y(0) = \int_{0}^{0} (y(t))^{\frac{1}{2}} dt + 1=1$$

The integral is zero..